# django context to built-in pages

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I have a template that looks something like:

Main Template, home.html:

```
{% extends "framed.html" %}
<h2> stuff <h2>
```

framed.html looks something like

```
{% block header %}
<h1>{{ sitename }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Normally when I call these views I give it a context with a context containing a key "sitename" assigned get_current_site().name, which works fine.

I also, however, would like to use framed.html at the top of a bunch of templates that are also called by django default views. For example:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login'))
```

The top of that page never gets the {{sitename}} to show up, so I end up with some blank space at the top of my page. The same goes for flat pages, logouts, etc. Is there a way I can get the relevant context added to all of these "built-in" pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own template context processor that will add required variable in the parameters provided to each template.

More details at [Writing your own context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)